# How to make my while-loop along with the user prompts work?

Tags: java, vector, while-loop, tostring

Over here, I have a robot application which consists of mainly three user prompts. Right after the third prompt, and it has to loop back to the first one and this goes on until when the user types **QUIT** which will then display all the details from the vector elements. Right now, I'm having problem with the application as when I put the first prompt in the `while-loop` and when the application starts, nothing happens unless I put it out of the loop but this will not be looping back. So could someone give me some guidance here as I'm a newbie in programming. Thanks so much!

```
class KillerRobot {

private String name;
private String mainWeapon;
private int numberOfKills;

KillerRobot()
{
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getMainWeapon()
{
    return mainWeapon;
}

public int getNumberOfKills()
{
    return numberOfKills;
}

public String toString()
{
    return name + " used a " + mainWeapon + " to destroy " + numberOfKills + " enemies ";
}

public void setName(String a)
{
    name = a;
}

public void setMainWeapon(String b)
{
    mainWeapon = b;
}

public void setNumberOfKills(int c)
{
    numberOfKills = c;
}
}
```

Main method class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

class TestVector2 {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String prompt = "Please enter the name of the Killer Robot or QUIT to finish";
    String prompt2 = "Please enter the main weapon for the robot";
    String prompt3 = "Please enter the number of kills for this robot";

    System.out.println(prompt);                     //The first prompt and has to loop back unless QUIT from user
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    Vector <KillerRobot> robotDetails = new Vector <KillerRobot>();     //adding object to Vector elements

    do {
        System.out.println(prompt);                 //The first prompt and has to loop back unless QUIT from user
        robot = new KillerRobot();

        String a = userInput.next();
        robot.setName(a);

        System.out.println(prompt2);
        String b  = userInput.next();
        robot.setMainWeapon(b);

        System.out.println(prompt3);
        int c = userInput.nextInt();
        robot.setNumberOfKills(c);

        robotDetails.add(robot);
        System.out.println(robot);
    } while (!userInput.nextLine().equals("QUIT"));
}           
}
```

Comment: `nothing happens unless I put it out of the loop` what will happen

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin oh hey hi erm i meant as in if i don't put `System.out.println(prompt)` out of the while loop, it won't work. it do compiles but nothing will show up on my console.

Comment: is that the problem??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin so my while loop is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should in line with what you want. There are a few changes - one your code has the prompt displayed twice, second you want them to be able to QUIT before having any robots so a do-while loop would be a little inconvenient, and lastly at the end of the loop I use prompt1 again and if they quit, print all the robots if there are any instead of printing them out in each iteration of the loop (because at that point if you just print it to the console you aren't using the vector at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String prompt1 = "Please enter the name of the Killer Robot or enter QUIT to exit.";
            String prompt2 = "Please enter the main weapon for the robot";
            String prompt3 = "Please enter the number of kills for this robot";
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

            Vector <KillerRobot> robotDetails = new Vector <KillerRobot>();
            KillerRobot robot;


            //prime the loop
            System.out.println(prompt1); 
            String userEntry = userInput.next();

            while(!userEntry.equals("QUIT")){
                robot = new KillerRobot();
                robot.setName(userEntry);

                System.out.println(prompt2);
                String b  = userInput.next();
                robot.setMainWeapon(b);

                System.out.println(prompt3);
                int c = userInput.nextInt();
                robot.setNumberOfKills(c);

                robotDetails.add(robot);

                //verify repeat
                System.out.println(prompt1); 
                userEntry = userInput.next();
            }

            if(robotDetails.size() < 1){
                System.out.println("No robots");
            } else {
                for(KillerRobot i : robotDetails){
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("done");
        }
```

Comment: yup I tried that before but still it doesn't work. :D

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 I ran your source and found a few quirks. I changed from a do-while to a while loop and the answer should reflect what would needed (I tested it). The problem with printing the details of the robot in the loop is that you really don't need the vector - you're storing the details for no reason. Give it a try and let me know. You should try more examples of loops on you're own though, most of what programming is is loops and understanding them is important.

Comment: Thank you so much Charles! Yeah it works exactly what is needed now. I do agree with you I need to try more loops examples but the most I'm confused about will be the utilizing of the next(), nextLine() or nextInt(). May I ask you why would you declare `String userEntry` outside the loop? Thanks! :D

Comment: In java, { ... } denotes scope. Also, calling a function denotes scope as well, but that is a bit different. I declare userEntry outside the loop because I need to be in the scope of the while loop test statement so that we can enter/not enter/exit the loop. If it were in the loop, only the contents of the loop would know about that and not the test statement outside of it (plus, I need it before we even get to the loop). Variable scope is very important, too - and keep in mind different languages have different rules to scope.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of your program is a bit off, and this is giving you problems. You want to keep looping over all three prompts until the user types 'QUIT'. This means that the first prompt must be inside the loop. So the trick is to make your `while`-condition different. Instead of checking whether there is any input (with `hasNext()`), check whether the last input was 'QUIT'.

One way to do that is to set a simple `boolean` flag outside the loop and then use that as your `while`-condition, like so:

```
 boolean quit = false;

 while(!quit) {
   System.out.println(prompt);
   String a = userInput.next(); 
   quit = "QUIT".equals(a); 
   ...
 }
```

This is actually still not ideal, since this will continue showing all three prompts, even when the user types 'QUIT' on the first one. I assume you want to jump out of the loop immediately when that happens, so you might consider making an infinite loop (using `while(true)`, for example), and just immediately jumping out of the loop (with a `break`) when the user enters the quit command.